# Multiple values per row in one hot encoding - is this recommended?

Tags: r, r-caret, one-hot-encoding

I'm using the `one_hot` function in `mltools` to convert a 2 variable molten data frame into a wide data frame where each variable (apart from an index) is a factor level.

There are 25,000 rows in the molten frame and only 2 variables - one a factor with 800 levels and one an index so I can merge back at a later point.

I'm going to use a variety of machine learning packages and hence need to represent the 800 factor levels in an acceptable way.

However, when I use `one_hot` I get a frame with 801 columns, which is correct (800 factor levels + 1 index) **but** I still have 25,000 rows. The number of original observations as represented as unique values in the index is 1,000.

So, my question is - is it best practice for one hot variables to only have one positive value per row? Is there a disadvantage to now collapse this down so each row is a single observation?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the question based on the information you gave.

You basically have **25,000 indexed observations** (represented by `id`) of **one variable** (the factor variable with 800 levels, represented by `val`). What you **can do** is:

1. Grouping by factor variable (e.g., via `group_by()`)
2. Adding a frequency count (e.g., via `freq = n()`)
3. One-hotting your variable (the `mltools` package is really great for that)

This will leave you **without your index**, but with a **2 x 801 table** that contains each **one-hotted variable** (columns 1:800) and their **frequency** (in column 801). Many frameworks can work with data like this very well, but it is impossible to answer specifically without further information.

```
> str(result)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  800 obs. of  801 variables:
 $ val_AAL5 : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ val_ABP14: int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ val_ACQ8 : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ val_ADU8 : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ val_AEB16: int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ val_AEX17: int  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ val_AGQ4 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ val_AHS8 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ val_AHV2 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ val_AHX16: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ val_AIV19: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
...
```

#### Code

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(val) %>%
    summarise(freq = n()) 
dt <- as.data.table(df)
result <- one_hot(dt)
```

#### Data

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(mltools)
set.seed(1701)
df <- data.frame(
    id = 1:25000,
    val = sample(paste0(sample(LETTERS[1:26], 800, replace = TRUE),
            sample(LETTERS[1:26], 800, replace = TRUE),
            sample(LETTERS[1:26], 800, replace = TRUE),
            sample(1:20, 20, replace = TRUE)),
        25000, replace = TRUE))

> head(df)
  id   val
1  1 CXC15
2  2 IPH16
3  3  ICK1
4  4  OPJ2
5  5  XSA8
6  6 JKS19
```